# C# How to access setter method on main form, from my user control?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, setter

I have a UserControl, that contains a panel, the panel contains a picture box.
When I MouseMove over the Picture Box, I want to update a label on the MainForm.
I have a get/set method on the main form, but how do I use it?? thanks

```
  public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public String MouseCords
        {
            get { return this.MouseCordsDisplayLabel.Text; }
            set { this.MouseCordsDisplayLabel.Text = value; }
        }
    }


    public partial class ScoreUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public ScoreUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ScorePictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // MainForm.MouseCords("Hello"); //What goes here?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's possible to do in your case like:

```
((MainForm)this.ParentForm).MouseCords = "Some Value Here";
```

But the right way is with events like Felice Pollano mentinoed:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.myCustomControlInstanse.PicureBoxMouseMove += new EventHandler<StringEventArgs>(myCustomControlInstanse_PicureBoxMouseMove);
    }

    private void myCustomControlInstanse_PicureBoxMouseMove(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MouseCordsDisplayLabel = e.Value // here is your value
    }
}


public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class ScoreUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> PicureBoxMouseMove;

    public void OnPicureBoxMouseMove(String value)
    {
        if (this.PicureBoxMouseMove != null)
            this.PicureBoxMouseMove(this, new StringEventArgs { Value = value });
    }

    public ScoreUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ScorePictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPicureBoxMouseMove("Some Text Here");
    }
}
```

Comment: And if he uses this control an a different type of form? 

You're right though - the Events / Observer approach is the correct one. We've both gone "quick and dirty"...

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should raise an event for the same.

Create a delegate

```
public delegate void  Update();
```

in the user control

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
public event Update OnUpdate;

}
```

On the main form register a handler for the user controls event.

```
public class Main
{
public Main()
{
myUserControl.OnUpdate += new Update(this.UpdateHandler);
}

void UpdateHandler()
{
//you can set the delegate with sm arguments
//set a property here

}
}
```

On user control,

To raise an event on button click

do this

```
OnUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might give you an idea...

```
    public partial class ScoreUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ScoreUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ScorePictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // MainForm.MouseCords("Hello"); //What goes here?
        MainForm parent = this.ParentForm as MainForm;
        if (parent != null) parent.MouseCordsDisplayLabel.Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Create an event on the user control and have to form listen to it (I think this is the recommended way by most C# programmers).
2. Pass a reference to the main form to the User Control (in the constructor). This way, the user control knows about its MainForm.
3. Cast `this.ParentForm` to the MainForm class, then you have the reference.

Options 2 and 3 are somewhat more comfortable and lazy, but the cost is that the user control has to know about the specific class MainForm. The first option has the advantage that you could reuse the user control in another project, because it does not know about the MainForm class.

Answer (score 0):

You should publish an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx) from the user control and subscribe to it from the main form.
At least this is the pattern suggested for winform. In any case the idea is to make the control "**observable**" from the agents who need to see the coords, instead of using it as a driver to update the interested agents.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do this.
I was trying that before I tried get/set methods.

Comment: there is a link in the answer that is a complete event tutorial, have a look

Comment: thank you felice, I'm  a massive noob here and C#, thanks for being so quick to reply and helpful.